# Mariadb trigger set specific row

Tags: triggers, mariadb

Hei, I got a trigger problem ...
I have a table DuelRound(Id, Status, Winner, RoundNumber, DuelId ..)
There are four rounds each Duel. So the Roundnumber indicates which round it is (from 0 to 3)
When I am updating the Status, I want to update the Status from the next Round.
But how can I get the next Round in a trigger ?

I tried something like that: (Before update)

```
BEGIN
    IF new.Status = 3 THEN  
        SET status = 1
        WHERE NEW.RoundNumber = DuelRound.RoundNumber -1
        AND NEW.DuelId = DuelRound.DuelId;      
    END IF;
    
END
```

But I cant use the variable Status there. Any Ideas ?

Comment: Edit: With that code, there is the error Unkown System Variable "Status"(1193)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a trigger to update the same table the trigger is attached to.

["A stored function or trigger cannot modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger."](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html)

What you can do instead, is to use a stored procedure which will do both updates in a transaction.

As for the error itself, the syntax `SET status = 1 WHERE` is incorrect, a trigger expects a valid SQL statement (`SET` does not have a WHERE-clause).

Comment: Thanks alot fot that fast answer! 
I will then try it with stored procedure :)